# Number Generator with User Input

Tags: java

Ok, I have wrote this RandomNumberGenerator.java class and I am getting an error.  Logically it looks like it would work but it is not. I need to have a random number  between the two input's that the user input's. Would someone take a look at my code and see where I am going wrong.  Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class NumberGenerator
{

// Begin 

  public static void main(String[] args){


  Scanner input;
  int max, min, range;
  Random gen;

  public static int genRandom(int mod){
    Random r = new Random();
  }


  input = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Please enter a max value: ");
  max = input.nextInt();

  // Ask user to input max value

  System.out.println(" Please enter a minimum value: ");
  min = input.nextInt();

  // Ask user to input min value

  range = Math.abs(r.nextInt()) % (max - min + 1) + min;
  // Get random integer between min and max values using %


  System.out.println(" Your generated number is: " + range );

  }
}
```

Comment: your error message is...? It seems that it would make sense to post this.

Comment: Also, please consider formatting your code, including reasonable and regular indentations, so we can be able to more easily read it and help you.

Comment: "... I am getting an error ..." - please be more specific.

Comment: To get good answers, a question ought to include what the expected output is, and what the actual output (or error message) is. (Don't paraphrase error messages: cut and paste them verbatim)

Comment: Your code is full of syntax errors. Read the error the compiler is giving you, think about it.

Comment: Having `genRandom` defined within `main` isn't going to work.  Try pulling `genRandom` out and having it either before or after `main`.

Answer (score 3):

Your code structure is incorrect. The getRandom(..) method is defined inside your main method. You also have scoping issues (you're defining the 'r' variable inside one method and attempting to use it in another).

Try starting small and concentrate on getting your indentation right, then these kinds of errors will become more apparent.

Comment: You got there before me!  You clearly didn't stroke your beard enough before posting.

Comment: @Wallace - that gave me a chuckle. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your method,

```
public static int genRandom(int mod){
    Random r = new Random();
}
```

is inside of your main method.  You can't declare one method inside of another just like that.    You should declare it outside of your main method.  Also, you've declared it to return an int, which means you actually have to make it return an int or it won't compile. So do it like this:

```
public static int genRandom(int mod){
    Random r = new Random();
    return r.nextInt(); // Add this line to return an int.
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
   // Call getRandom() in here where appropriate
}
```

**NOTE**
The gist of this answer is to help you understand why your code isn't compiling.  Even if you get your code to compile, it still probably won't behave correctly.  The other answers give you good solutions to make it work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Following Code Will Work. Basically you have a non final method inside main method.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberGenerator {

    // Begin

    static Random r = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input;
        int max, min, range;
        Random gen;

        input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a max value: ");
        max = input.nextInt(); // Ask user to input max value

        System.out.println(" Please enter a minimum value: ");
        min = input.nextInt(); // Ask user to input min value

        range = Math.abs(r.nextInt()) % (max - min + 1) + min;
        // Get random integer between min and max values using %

        System.out.println(" Your generated number is: " + range);

    }
}
```

Comment: Why is r static? And why do you have two Random objects.  Pun not intended.

Comment: Yeah it isn't intended, basically I copied his code and moved that method out as static Random.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class RandomRange {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int min = 50;
    int max = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      int rnd = (int) ((Math.random() * (max + 1 - min))) + min;
      System.out.println(rnd);
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Your version here is never going to give `min` as a result.  This makes it worse, not better.

Comment: To be fair, at least it would compile.

Answer (score 0):

You declare an object:

```
Random gen;
```

Then you create a method called `genRandom(int mod)` which instantiates  a new Random object '`r`'.  Which is INSIDE your main method. Which isn't correct.

Then when you go to call a method to get a random number you choose to use '`r`' which is not in the scope of the statement.

Developers don't let developers code recklessly.
Now I'ma need to take your keyboard.